# userDefault value is not updated until the closing the app

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem with userDefault, @Sh_Khan helped me on that but I couldn't fix the problem yet, so I ask it here with more details.

I created a `userDefault` to store a username

```
let user_name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_name")
```

I have a login page that when user taps on the login button, the username is saved in the `UserDefaults`.

```
let username = usernameInput?.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

   @IBAction func pressLoginBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
   UserDefaults.standard.setValue(username, forKey: "user_name")
...
}
```

It saved and worked well, then in a profile page, which is a `UIViewController`, I have a logout button to send user back to the login page.

In this case, I assumed when user add a new username, the old value should replaced immediately with the new one, but It does, but the new value the `UserDefaults` still present the old value until I close the app and open it again, then it shows the new value

So, I tried to remove the value when the user click on the logout button:

```
  @IBAction func pressLogutBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "user_name")
        print(user_name)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login")
        self.present(mainStoryboard,animated:true,completion:nil)
    }
```

The funny thing is, in the second line, I remove the value, but in the next line when I print it, it is still exist.

For the test, I add this print in the `viewDidLoad` in the profile page.

```
print(user_name)
```

Then, for example user add `mrX` username, so when the profile page is opened, it prints `mrX`. Then I press on logout and enter `mrY` username. Then when the profile page is opened, it still prints `mrX`, this process can be repeated many times and it still print `mrX`, until I close the app completely, then It prints `mrY`.

could anyone help on this? I really don't understand what is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read data instantly from `userDefaults` by the way you use.

instead of this way:

```
print(user_name)
```

You should use:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_name")!)
```